# grey box AJS.js file conflicking with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, slider, jcarousel

Im using http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox  for popup in my application everything was working fine until i added Jcarousal from http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel
Now greybox is working but jcarousal is not working when i comment the line in greybox as you can see in code then jcarousal dont work. how can i avoid this confliction

```
<link href="Script/greybox/gb_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var GB_ROOT_DIR = '<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("../Script/greybox/")%>';
</script>   
<%--<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("../Script/greybox/AJS.js") %>'></script>--%>**// if i comment this line then jcarousal works**
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("../Script/greybox/AJS_fx.js") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("../Script/greybox/gb_scripts.js") %>'></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put this line after you include jQuery but before you call other javascript library.

```
$.noConflict():
```